# Connected components of a graph

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am trying to find the number of connected components of numerous named graphs within Combinatorica. The obvious answer seems to be:

```
Length[GraphData[G,"ConnectedComponents"]]
```

but this fails. What am I doing wrong?

Does this property only work when the number of connected components is >= 2?

Comment: Please give a complete and runnable example which fails.  What is "G"?  Also, GraphData is not part of Combinatorica.  Do not load Combinatorica for this.

Comment: I am using version 9 of Mathematica. Has the use of Combinatorica` changed from earlier versions? I have been using GraphData with Combinatorica` for a long time.

Comment: `GraphData` is not part of Combinatorica, and to my knowledge it has never been.  It is a built-in function introduced in version 8.

Comment: I have to correct myself, `GraphData` was introduced in version 6, but it was a built-in, not part of Combinatorica.  In version 8 and version 9 it returns the new `Graph` objects that were introduced in version 8.  These are not directly compatible with Combinatorica.  While it is still possible to use Combinatorica, and even convert these built-in graphs to Combinatorica's format, great care has to be taken to choose the correct function from the correct context for each operation.  So unless you know you *need* Combinatorica, I recommend you don't load it to avoid accidental problems.

Comment: `GraphData["PappusGraph", "Properties"]` shows that this graph has no property called "ConnectedComponents" in version 9.  It has `GraphData["PappusGraph", "ConnectedComponentCount"]` which returns 1.

Comment: Thank you - this is very helpful. Clive

Answer (score 5):

Negotiating between system and Combinatorica is tricky. I post this for illustrative purposes.Notes also `ConnectedComponents` is a built-in command in Mathematica 9.

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
fg = FiniteGraphs;
adj = ToAdjacencyMatrix /@ fg;
sysg = System`AdjacencyGraph /@ adj;
Grid[Partition[
  Row /@ ({#, Length[System`ConnectedComponents[#]]} & /@ sysg), 5], 
 Frame -> All]
```

[image]